# What if an earth like planet was physically split in half and then immediately rejoined (a bit tilted)?

Tags: planets, magic, climate, science-in-society

I'm sorry I was not clear enough with my question, I'll try to summarize in the final paragraph:

A world where magic is real, and godlike creatures fought each other on a regular basis, ending up with a huge battle where one sends a strike (a god slice) so large that he splits the planet in half, all others involved try to avoid total destruction and "mend" the planet together, but the end result is a huge range of mountains miles and miles in depth, that pretty much divides the planet in 2 halves.

I would like to hypothesize what the end result of such an event would have on regular non godlike life within the planet, if, such life was intelligent and somewhat capable of having some magic and some middle aged technology.
As someone already stated "magic" can do *anything* I want to somewhat limit the strength of such magic so that it does have an effect on the world, but not overtly *can do anything* magic.

Suppose this gods are able to somewhat *build* a force field to stop the halves of the planet from disintegration and *then* push them back to their place, a few minutes after the fact,

Would it be possible to avoid total extinction?

Sorry again for my bad question, first time here.
Thank you all for your help.

Comment: ... What's the question?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Worldbuilding! I'm not overly sure what exactly you want to know - do you want to know if such a thing is possible? Or do you want to know what would happen to the planet if such an event actually happened?

Comment: I would like to hypothesize what the end result of such an event would have on regular non godlike life within the planet, if such life was intelligent and somewhat capable of having some magic and some middle aged technology

Comment: @Comorv Edit your question to include your request in the comments. It might improve the questions score.

Comment: I want to vote this closed but it doesn't technically meet the criteria.

Comment: To make this answerable... You need to specify what the question is in the question (not comments). You need to specify _how_ the planet was cleaved apart (impact, magical slice, etc). You need to specify how long the two pieces were separate and how far apart they drifted. You need to specify whether or not magic was used to keep the two halves intact while they were split. You need to specify how large the displacement was when it got stuck back together. You need to specify whether or not magic is supporting the shape of the displaced parts.

Comment: Invoking *magic* and *gods* pretty much rules out any logical process, as you can basically make *anything* you want to happen afterwards happen.  So what would it be like - it would be whatever way you want it to be.

Comment: @StephenG *no*. Invoking magic and gods is just normal worldbuilding. As long as the process is well-defined we can base any answers on the rules and axioms defined in the question

Answer (score 2):

No, everyone is going to die.

Even if the slice was done by parting via a magic "force field" so that you can ignore the 'damage'. Ditto for the rejoin.

Edge effects from having the planet split will begin immediately. The atmosphere, oceans, and liquid rock will begin to spill out. The suddenly depressurized surface at the edge will being to expand. These effects will be large scale and significant.

If you just join the planet together again, all of the "spilled" material will suddenly be compressed again with catastrophic effect.

If your duration of the time of the split earth is so small to preclude significant edge effects (perhaps microseconds or less), there will not be time to twist the 2 halves so that they no longer line up as before. -- At least not without catastrophic rates of acceleration (to twist the halves).

So, if you do this without killing everyone, you don't have a discontinuity at join either. It is as if it never happened.

Answer (score 1):

The force of impact alone from the slice would kill all life on its surface.

As would pushing it back together

as would exposing the core

so basically all life on earth would be killed 3 times over

Comment: Thank you, yes I think that too, I'm getting to that in this world I'm building, but it probably fails within this particular parameter (even as huge magic may be involved)...

Comment: Well then the question should be closed because you have not described the limitations of magic. Once you throw unregulated magic into the equation the answer becomes "because I feel like it". With the village people rejoicing as if nothing happened at all.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that planets do not behave like apples. You can cut an apple in half and it stays the same shape. Not so with planets. It would be impossibly difficult to cut using real methods and even if you used magical methods the gravitational effects on the two halves would draw each hemisphere into a smaller sphere as soon as they were separated.

Cutting a planet in half would also have massive internal effects disrupting plate tectonics, interrupting core rotation and causing phase changes in the core as the over pressure was released. The energy released would probably be sufficient to melt the crust in its entirety or at least large parts of it.

If you are going to use magic, then why not simply have one of the gods form the mountains in a fit of magical temper?

Comment: I disagree, if you cut a planet with a wedge shaped god sword fast enough, that would impart enough outward push for the halves to initially float apart. Of course gravity would bring them back together eventually. We need mythbusters

Comment: Well its true I suppose. With magic anything is possible.